# Zsh: how to see all buffers?

Tags: buffer, zsh

You can push things to buffer with `^Q` and pop them with `ESC-g`. `Alt+x vi-set-buffer` changes buffer somehow. How can I see all the buffers? They are probably some files to look at.

Answer (score 1):

`^Q` (and `Esc-Q`) and `Esc-g` work with an emacs buffer, so I don't think they interact with the vi buffers.

This works in emacs mode (`set -o emacs`):

```
function _showbuffers()
{
    local nl=$'\n' kr
    typeset -T kr KR $'\n'
    KR=($killring)
    typeset +g -a buffers
    buffers+="      Pre: ${PREBUFFER:-$nl}"
    buffers+="  Buffer: $BUFFER$nl"
    buffers+="     Cut: $CUTBUFFER$nl"
    buffers+="       L: $LBUFFER$nl"
    buffers+="       R: $RBUFFER$nl"
    buffers+="Killring:$nl$nl$kr"
    zle -M "$buffers"
}
zle -N showbuffers _showbuffers
bindkey "^[o" showbuffers
```

To demonstrate it, try each of these steps, pressing Alt-o (letter "O") or Esc-o after each one:

- To show the cut buffer, type `echo abc` then press Ctrl-u
- To show the kill ring (the previous cut buffer moves there), type `echo def` then press Ctrl-u (or Home Ctrl-K or Ctrl-X Ctrl-K)
- To show the pre buffer, type `echo 'ghi`, press enter, type `jkl'`
- Press enter to execute the previous command and clear the current buffer (don't forget to press Alt-o to see the change)
- To show the L and R buffers, type `echo "mno pqr"` and press the left arrow a couple of times

Comment: "To show" means "to demonstrate" since all the included buffers are shown with each invocation.